# How to selectively unbind a delegated event on an element?

Tags: jquery

Consider the following code:

```html
    <div class="parent1">
      <div class="child">child1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent2">
      <div class="child">child2</div>
    </div>
```

If a mouseenter event is bounded to .child as

```js
   $(document).on("mouseover mouseout", ".child", function(){ ..}
```

how to unbind this for .parent2.child alone, but still have it binded for .parent1.child ?

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) should do...

```
$(".parent2 .child").unbind("mouseover mouseout");
```

**EDIT**
Since `.child` are dynamically inserted, try this:

```
$(".parent2").find(".child").unbind("mouseover mouseout");
```

Comment: Is `.child` dynamically appended ?

Comment: Yes @Louys. .child is dynamically inserted into the DOM

Answer (score 1):

<s>I believe you should use the document since that is where this is bound, then find those children and do `off()`</s>

```
$(document).find(".parent2").off("mouseover mouseout", ".child");
```

I tested using revised markup, making the assumption that you simply did not properly close your div with the

```
<div class="parent1">
      <div class="child">child1</div>
<div>...
```

I used this markup to test (divs are peer/siblings rather than grand child).  Clarify if that is NOT a correct assumption by posting correct markup.

```
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="child">child1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
  <div class="child">child2</div>
</div>
```

Turns out that after testing the first attempt did NOT work.  This is because the event binds to the document, then filters by the children with the class `.child` selector, firing when it has a proper element.  I was unable to change that "filter" on those bindings so I had to simply "redo" the binding, filtering on the new children - which will NOT properly work IF you add new elements AFTER this - you will need to execute this IF you subsequently re-add more children - notice it binds to the `.child` not document.  Not a perfect scenario but the best I could find.

```
$(document).off("mouseover mouseout", ".child").find('.child').filter(function() {
  return !$(this).parents(".parent2").length;
}).on("mouseover mouseout", function() {
 console.log("new " + $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Your solution was almost close. It removed the binding for all elements with .child class